# Use different configuration sources as input to waf's doxygen feature

Tags: python, doxygen, waf

Based on the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47396160/8972161), where I wanted to use different sources based on the build variant specified, it now appears that I have the same problem for building the doxygen documentation, as I need different configurations based on the build variant.

The example stays quite the same, but gets a little longer:

---

The directory structure looks like this:

- doc

  - a.conf # config of doxygen sources for source a
  - b.conf # config of doxygen sources for source b
  - stylesheetfile # the same for both
- src

  - a.c
  - b.c
- doxygen.py
- wscript

The waf `doxygen.py` implementation is the same as on repository on GitHub of the waf project [doxygen.py](https://github.com/waf-project/waf/blob/master/waflib/extras/doxygen.py).

---

The waf script is extend to accept the `doxygen` option. But inside the definition of `doxygen` it is not possible to check against the build variant (here `bld.variant`) and this leads to an error as there seems no build variant defined in the doxygen feature.

The part where I check for the build variant is marked in the example with arrows.

**What, where and how do I have to implement changes, that the doxygen feature works and uses the correct configuration based on the build variant.**

MWE:

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load(['doxygen'], tooldir=os.path.join('doxygen.py'))

def configure(ctx):
    load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
    if not bld.variant:
        bld.fatal('call 'waf build_a' or 'waf build_b', and try 'waf --help'')

    if bld.variant == 'a':
        bld.program(source='a.c', target='app', includes='.',  features=['doxygen'])
    elif bld.variant == 'b':
        bld.program(source='b.c', target='app', includes='.', features=['doxygen'])
    else:
        bld.fatal('err')

# create build and clean commands for each build context
from waflib.Build import BuildContext, CleanContext

for x in 'a b'.split():
    for y in (BuildContext, CleanContext):
        name = y.__name__.replace('Context','').lower()
        class tmp(y):
            __doc__ = '''executes the {} of {}'''.format(name, x)
            cmd = name + '_' + x
            variant = x

def doxygen(bld):
    import sys
    import logging
    from waflib import Logs

    if bld.env.DOXYGEN:
        if bld.variant == 'a':    # <=================
            _conf = 'src/a.conf'  # <=================
        elif bld.variant == 'b':  # <=================
            _conf = 'src/b.conf'  # <=================
        else:                     # <=================
            bld.fatal('err')      # <=================

        bld.logger = Logs.make_logger('doxy.log', out)
        hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        bld.logger.addHandler(hdlr)

        bld(features='doxygen', doxyfile=_conf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not defined your variants for the doxygen command. You should add something like:

```py
variants = ['a', 'b']

for variant in variants:
    dox = "doxygen"
    class tmp(BuildContext):
        __doc__ = '''executes the {} of {}'''.format(dox, variant)
        cmd = dox + '_' + variant
        fun = dox
        variant = variant
```

A minimal working example:

```py
def configure(conf):
    pass

def doxygen(bld):
    print "variant =", bld.variant

# Create build commands with variants

from waflib.Build import BuildContext

variants = ['a', 'b']
for variant in variants:
    dox = "doxygen"
    class tmp(BuildContext):
        __doc__ = '''executes the {} of {}'''.format(dox, variant)
        cmd = dox + '_' + variant
        fun = dox
        variant = variant
```